# Youtube api 3 - Remove video from a dynamically generated Playlist.

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm using an embed player and appending a list of ids to the playlist.
I'm trying to remove one of this items without reloading the player.

I couldn't find a method to remove items added to player via cuePlaylist function.

Is this posible?

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerChange,
        },
    });
}

function onPlayerReady() {
    playerReady = true;
    videoList = ['bpOR_HuHRNs','esirnL3nN30', 'Qhc08Tccbf4'];
    player.cuePlaylist({
            'playlist': videoList,
        });
}

function onPlayerChange(event) {
    switch (event.data) {
        case 5:
            player.playVideo();
            break;
        case 0:
            console.log('ended');
            break;
    }
}
```

[full code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhLpaxc3/)

Comment: Could you load a new playlist that just excludes the video you wanted to delete? For example, if you wanted to delete videoList[1], create a new playlist with videoList[0] and video[List[2] as its elements, then load that. However, I don't know if you can do that without having to reload the player.

Comment: I found a workaround, reloading the player when the current video ends , then  append the updated video list to the new player. This way the user experience is not interrupted. I'm using this solution while looking for a more elegant way to do this.